# Extract Site Collection Properties to File

Tags: powershell, site, properties, file, collection

Is there a way to extract all the Site Collection properties to a file using SharePoint Management Shell

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way unless you find some utility function where you pass an object which will use Reflection to extract all properties

Good old way is to

```
Get-SPSite 'http://sitecollectionurl'
```

That can give you an [SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) Object. Now you can choose the properties of your interest and put it into a text file using

```
Out-File 'FileName.Txt' - Append
```

Final command will be like

```
Get-SPSite http://yourserver/sites/yoursite | Select Url, Owner | Out-File -FilePath c:\site.txt -append
```

Comment: Thanks :)
How about getting properties like port number, app pool etc.?

Comment: For that you should use `Get-SPWebApplication` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607562.aspx... Also for getting PORT and APPPOOL etc you should use Windows PowerShell Command..http://melcher.it/2013/03/powershell-list-all-iis-webapplications-net-version-state-identity/